# yarn not working with nexus 3 npm proxy repository

Tags: angular, npm, nexus, yarnpkg, nexus3

I have set up a Nexus 3 Manager to host private npm packages. The nexus contains three npm repositories, one `hosted`, one `proxy` and one `group` to combine the other two. The `npm bearer realm` if activated and i am using a nexus user with admin role for testing.

I have now set up a simple angular library via the angular cli for publishing. In the angular project i configured the `.npmrc` like follows:

```
registry=https://urlToMyNexus/repo/npm-all/
_authToken=NpmToken.XXXX
```

Now i want to install all packages over the set up group repository in nexus via `yarn install`. The `.npmrc` and `.yarnrc` in home home dictionary are empty.

The preconfigured `package.json` looks looks like follows:

```
{
  "name": "test-libraries",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.901.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "ng-packagr": "^9.0.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3"
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

The `yarn install` command is now able to install all `@angular` packages in the `dependencies`, but fails at `rxjs`. It gives the error `error Couldn't find package "rxjs" on the "npm" registry.`

If I try `npm install` with the same configuration all packages are installed correctly over the nexus repository.

Does anybody had the same problem?

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same problem this week. When I use yarn it fails with `error Couldn't find package "@egjs/hammerjs" on the "npm" registry.` After unistalling node_modules and yarn.lock it can show another package name, but error is the same. However, if I use `npm install` instead yarn - installation works fine. In my case, it's not an option, because project is more than a year in development and I don't want to replace package manager because of it. I will investigate this further and edit this post if I would find a solution that works with yarn

**Update:**
For me following steps did resolve this issue:

1. remove .yarnrc and .npmrc file
2. run command `yarn config delete registry` to delete current registry url from yarn inner config
3. Create .npmrc with following content

```
registry=https://nexus-registry-url.com
always-auth=true
_auth=<base64-token-value>
```

After this steps `yarn install` works for my local machine and for our project CI/CD in docker.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I can not delete the default yarn registry

Comment: `always-auth=true` did the trick. I had to add it manually since it is not a valid setting from NPM version 7+, so `npm config set always-auth true` doesn't work. Luckily, modern NPM just ignores it.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to add this in .npmrc to be always authenticated:

```
always-auth=true
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the `yarn.lock` file. The lockfile generated by yarn includes the registry for all the dependencies installed. If you want to change the registry, you will need to delete the `yarn.lock` file and run `yarn install` again. That should use the new registry set in the `.npmrc` file.